# Name of Variables with Slashes possible?

Tags: escaping

I have an SQL query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `ui_datenbank` 
            SET `bookgenre`='".$result->results[0]->genre/_text."'
            WHERE  `link`='".$row['link']."'") OR DIE(mysql_error());
```

But I get this error message: *Warning: Division by zero in /www/htdocs/.../mdp2.php* on line 49.

My Question: I get this error because of the >>_<< or >>/<< characters?

Here is my Source:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [genre/_source] => /search?genre=g_Abenteuer
            [genre/_text] => Abenteuer
            [filmtitel] => Außer Dienst - Helmut Schmidt
            [genre] => Bookgenre-URL
            [sprache] => German
        )

)
```

Comment: is this a typo ? `genre/_text`

Comment: I added the source in my first Post. I don't think, that it is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The `/`; it is being interpreted as a division symbol.  If that really is the name of the field of `results[0]` that you want, you'll need to specify it another way.  For example, put the name in a variable (say, `name`), and the refer to the field using `results[0]->$name`.

Comment: How can I specify it another way? I can not rename the "genre/_text", because I get the JSON File from an external source.